# Is it possible to obtain information about a trigger within the trigger execution?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm looking to create a table that I can use for overriding trigger execution (so, turn them on and off individually according to a database value). I was interested in doing this by using table name and trigger name, to account for multiple triggers, which lead me to a question of interest; is it possible to obtain information about a trigger, such as its name and the table its executing on, within the execution of the trigger?

Comment: Please add a tag for your database system. Triggers are highly product specific. [tag:sql] refers to the standard SQL language, not a specific product.

Comment: But I will add, in most database systems I'm aware of, there's no real way to write a "generic" trigger - each trigger has to be customized for each table it will apply to, so usually there's no need to do any runtime discovery since you can just apply further customization when you customize it for each table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use the @@PROCID and OBJECT_NAME functions to get the name of the trigger (or stored procedure) which is executing. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (SomeColumn INT)

GO
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable 
FOR INSERT
AS
PRINT OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)
DECLARE @TableName sysname
SET @TableName=(SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id=@@PROCID)
PRINT @TableName

GO
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (SomeColumn) VALUES (1)
```

Comment: But as I said, there's no way to write this trigger so that it applies to multiple tables. So if you're e.g. generating multiple triggers via dynamic SQL, you may as well just substitute in the `MyTrigger` and `MyTable` values inside the body of the trigger at the same time as you're inserting them into the `CREATE TRIGGER` line.